# Entity Framework: A referential integrity constraint violation occurred

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-4.1, webforms

I'm developing a `asp.net Web Forms application with Entity Framework`. When i'm trying to update `PROVINCE_ID` from existing data in `DISTRICT` Table (I changed `PROVINCE_ID` that selected previously in one entry and tried to update.), i got below error.

```
A referential integrity constraint violation occurred: A primary key property that is a part of referential integrity constraint cannot be changed when the dependent object is Unchanged unless it is being set to the association's principal object. The principal object must be tracked and not marked for deletion.
```

Table structure is below.

[image]

**UPDATED**

Code in aspx page.

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

    <asp:EntityDataSource ID="District_EDS" runat="server" ConnectionString="name=ABC_DBEntities"
        DefaultContainerName="ABC_DBEntities" EnableFlattening="False" EntitySetName="DISTRICT"
        EnableUpdate="True" Where="it.DISTRICT_ID = @DISTRICT_ID">
        <WhereParameters>
            <asp:QueryStringParameter DbType="String" Name="DISTRICT_ID" QueryStringField="DISTRICT_ID" />
        </WhereParameters>
    </asp:EntityDataSource>
    <%--DropDownList Entity Data Source--%>
    <asp:EntityDataSource ID="Province_EDS" runat="server" ConnectionString="name=ABC_DBEntities"
        DefaultContainerName="ABC_DBEntities" EnableFlattening="False" EntitySetName="PROVINCE"
        EnableUpdate="True">
    </asp:EntityDataSource>
    <asp:DetailsView ID="District_DV" runat="server" AutoGenerateRows="False" DefaultMode="Edit"
        DataKeyNames="DISTRICT_ID,PROVINCE_ID" DataSourceID="District_EDS" OnItemCommand="District_DV_ItemCommand">
        <Fields>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="District Id *" SortExpression="DISTRICT_ID">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("DISTRICT_ID") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("DISTRICT_ID") %>'></asp:Label>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <InsertItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("DISTRICT_ID") %>'></asp:Label>
                </InsertItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Province Name *" SortExpression="PROVINCE_ID">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("PROVINCE_ID") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_PROVINCE_id" Width="200" runat="server" DataSourceID="Province_EDS"
                        DataTextField="PROVINCE_NAME" DataValueField="PROVINCE_ID" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("PROVINCE_ID") %>'>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="PROVINCE_ID_VAL" runat="server" ControlToValidate="ddl_PROVINCE_id"
                        ErrorMessage="Province Name is required." ValidationGroup="DISTRICT"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <InsertItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("PROVINCE_ID") %>'></asp:Label>
                </InsertItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="District Name *" SortExpression="DISTRICT_NAME">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("DISTRICT_NAME") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txt_DISTRICT_name" Width="200" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("DISTRICT_NAME") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="DISTRICT_NAME_VAL" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txt_DISTRICT_name"
                        ErrorMessage="District Name is required." ValidationGroup="DISTRICT"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <InsertItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("DISTRICT_NAME") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </InsertItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="true" ShowCancelButton="false" ValidationGroup="DISTRICT" />
        </Fields>
    </asp:DetailsView>
</asp:Content>
```

CodeBehind

```
  // Return to index page after updating content on the page.
    protected void District_DV_ItemCommand(Object sender, DetailsViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "Update")
        {
            Response.Redirect("~/District/Index.aspx", false);

        }
    }
```

How cloud i solve this ?

Comment: this means that the new province id is not found in the province table

Comment: @Ahmad. no. i'm using `DropDownList` to select `PROVINCE_ID`. data filling to `DropDownList` from database table `PROVINCE`.

Comment: so make sure that the values of the dropdown are correct ( check the rendered HTML )

Comment: @Ahmad i have checked it. no problem there.

Comment: Do you try to update by writing explicit code? (If yes, please show the code.) Or does it happen via some webforms data source control that has an update feature built in? (If yes, details about the control you are using, how it is configured and how you bind your data to it might be helpful.)

Comment: @Bishan Can you post your Entity Framework code which you are trying to update with? Also make sure that the province_id in consideration is also attached to the same context.

Comment: @Bishan, where is the code which actually does the update?

Comment: @BishnuPaudel `CURD` operations are handle by `EntityFrameWork`

Comment: Entity Framework code calls is where this exception originates. please include code of CRUD operations if you want an answer with meaning.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this might be of some guidance:
https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/ASPNET-MVC-Application-b01a9fe8/sourcecode?fileId=134759&pathId=2009908151

```
private void UpdateInstructorCourses(string[] selectedCourses, Instructor instructorToUpdate) 
    { 
        if (selectedCourses == null) 
        { 
            instructorToUpdate.Courses = new List<Course>(); 
            return; 
        } 

        var selectedCoursesHS = new HashSet<string>(selectedCourses); 
        var instructorCourses = new HashSet<int> 
            (instructorToUpdate.Courses.Select(c => c.CourseID)); 
        foreach (var course in db.Courses) 
        { 
            if (selectedCoursesHS.Contains(course.CourseID.ToString())) 
            { 
                if (!instructorCourses.Contains(course.CourseID)) 
                { 
                    instructorToUpdate.Courses.Add(course); 
                } 
            } 
            else 
            { 
                if (instructorCourses.Contains(course.CourseID)) 
                { 
                    instructorToUpdate.Courses.Remove(course); 
                } 
            } 
        } 
    }
```